# Adding a qualifier/label to a namespace

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, prototype

I'm developing a Javascript API. One of its parts is a JSON decoder which takes a JSON string and then builds the proper object for programmer to use. Some of these objects are standard in the API, but most of them will be application *ad hoc* childs of those standard objects.

These application *ad hoc* objects will be auto-generated prior to Javascript development, and they will live in a namespace (with its name being different between applications).

Let's say one of those JSON strings could be `{"Foo":{"bar":"Hello world!"}}` and should produce an object `Foo` which property `bar` has `Hello, world!` as value. This JSON decoder will check if `Foo` is one of the standard prototypes and if it isn't, then it should check all of the application *ad hoc* namespaces (we could assume there will be just one, but this question applies for multiple namespaces too).

So first problem: find those namespaces. Let's find some options:

- One of the options could be creating a method in the JSON decoder which stores namespaces to check them later (this method should be called every time one of these namespaces is created). However this introduces some coupling since scripts which define those namespaces require the JSON decoder to be already available for use. I wouldn't want this one.
- Another option could be having a global variable where namespaces register themselves upon construction and decoder browses there. This option is very similar to first one but it pollutes global namespace. I wouldn't want this one.
- A third option could be labeling these namespaces in some way, so JSON decoder can (when loading) browse `window` and store locally all of the namespaces with that label. That would mean adding a property to those namespaces, for example `IsAFoo` but it must have a value which, in this case, won't be used at all. Then we would simply loop over window keys and check for `window[entry].hasOwnProperty("IsAFoo");` to store them. I wouldn't want this one because of the uninteresting value.
- My last option would be making these namespaces be an instance of a "super namespace". We could imagine we have an object which will act as namespace. We could even make them inherit this super namespace, but it's not necessary. So let's extend a bit more this fourth option, since it's the one I chose.

Imagine we've got this object, which is part of the standard API and will be what we call the "super namespace":

```
var MyCustomQualifier = function (objects) {
    // copy all of the entries to the namespace
    for(var entry in objects) {
        if(objects.hasOwnProperty(entry)) {
            this[entry] = objects[entry];
        }
    }
};
```

And let's say we've got one of those standard API objects like this:

```
var SuperFoo = function () {

};
```

Now, the following code would be the auto-generated one, including the namespace's name:

```
var MyGlobalNamespace = MyGlobalNamespace || (function () {
    var Foo = function (bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    };
    Foo.prototype = new SuperFoo();
    Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;

    Foo.prototype.say = function () {
        return this.bar;
    };

    return new MyCustomQualifier({
        Foo : Foo
    });
})();
```

So this way we've got in `MyGlobalNamespace` all of the objects for our application using the standard API objects and giving it custom business logic.

We could execute the following code, for example, to check if everything's working as expected:

```
// this variable would be what the decoder would build,
// but we create it manually here
var foo = new MyGlobalNamespace.Foo("Hello, world!");

console.log("Foo says:", foo.say());
console.log("foo is instance of Foo?", foo instanceof MyGlobalNamespace.Foo);
console.log("foo is instance of SuperFoo?", foo instanceof SuperFoo);

for(var entry in window) {
    if(window[entry] instanceof MyCustomQualifier) {
        console.log(entry + " is a MyCustomQualifier!");
    }
}
```

It will output:

```
Foo says: Hello, world!
foo is instance of Foo? true
foo is instance of SuperFoo? true
MyGlobalNamespace is a MyCustomQualifier!
```

So what do you think about these options and my answer to fourth option? Do you have any extra ways to do this? It's important that code is in pure Javascript with no frameworks.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd say the most logical solution would be to add metadata to the JSON object. Something like: { "fqn":"org.example.Foo", "members": {"bar":"Hello world!"}}